# Is the relation between all equations and all curves in plane surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, curves, plane-geometry, plane-curves

Let $O$ be the infinite? set of all operations such as addition, multiplication, trigonometric functions, integrals etc, over the independent variables $x$ and $y$.
Let $H_0$ be a subset of $O$.
$$H_1 = \{r \circ t \rvert r,t \in H_0\}$$
$$H_i=\{r \circ t \rvert r,t \in \bigcup_{k=0}^{i-1} H_i\}$$

By $H_1$ I mean all possible compositions of operations in $H_0$. For example: 
If $H_0=\{+,*\}$ then the expressions $x+x;x+y;x*y$ would be part of $H_1$ then $x*x*y;x*x+x;x+x*x$ would be part of $H_2$ and so on.

Let $C$ be the set of all curves on the $xy$ plane. We can impose further restrictions on $C$ such as all curves must have no intersections, or be [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness), to have or not have branches (such as the graphs of hyperbolas)

Given a set $H_0$ let $E = \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty H_i$. $E_k(x,y) \in E$.
$E_k(x,y)$ is an expression in terms of $x$ and $y$ obtained by any number of compositions of operations from $H_0$
For the implicit equation $E_k(x,y)=0$ let $I_k$ be the curve of the solution to the previous equation.
$I= \bigcup_{E_k \in E} I_k$

My question: For a given $H_0$ and a set of restrictions on $C$ does $C \in I$?
 Is the relation $F:E \mapsto C$, $F:=E_k(x,y)=0$,  surjective?
Follow-up and more concrete questions and examples:

1.What is the minimum set $H_0$ for which all graphs of the implicit equations $E_k(x,y)=0$ cover all smooth (with intersections and branches) curves in $C$? 
2.Are the common operations such as $+,-,*,/$ and functions such as trigonometric, exponential, logarithmic enough to cover all smooth curves in plane? If not do we need more functions such as the transcendental one [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and other similar to it? Maybe even limits and integrals?
3. Given an $H_0$ and a squiggly curve (smooth with intersections and no branches) can we prove the existence of an implicit equation $E_k(x,y)=0$ for which the solution graph $I_k$ is exactly our squiggly curve? Even if we can't find the expression $E_k(x,y)$ can we tell if it exists or not for a given $H_0$?

For all $E_k(x,y)=0$ assume maximum domain $D \in \Bbb R$ where $x,y \in D$ for which $E_k(x,y)=0$ is well defined.

In common language and ignoring a lot of constrains, it all comes down to: Can we map all implicit equations to curves in plane **and** vice-versa?

**Edit**
As pointed out by a comment I need to define what do I mean by "curve".
I don't have a proper technical definition but I was thinking of a curve as being any continuous non straight line in plane. It can have branches such as the hyperbola and it doesn't have to be locally differentiable everywhere like a polygon.
But it can have further restrictions such as being of a certain $C^i$ degree of smoothness.

For this question any formal definition of a "curve" can do just fine. I'm interested if the question can be answered for any definition.

Comment: You never defined a "curve". That's the main point. How do you define a curve?